# how to echo the filename?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm searching in a .docx content with this command:

```
unzip -p *.docx word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g' | grep $1
```

But I need the name of file which contains the word what I searched. How can I do it?

Comment: use `grep -l` instead of sed + grep.. what is the output of `unzip -p`? if it is list of filenames, you need `xargs` to pass it onto grep

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent [`zipgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipgrep). Look at its source; it's not very complex.

Comment: unzip -p outbut the source of .docx file

Comment: @LaveauAnderson try `zipgrep -l` as suggested by tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can walk through the files via `for` cycle:

```
for file in *.docx; do
  unzip -p "$file" word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]]\{1,\}//g' | grep PATTERN && echo $file
done
```

The `&& echo $file` part prints the filename when grep finds the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! You are the real MVP :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
find . -name "*your_file_name*" | xargs grep your_word | cut -d':' -f1
```

Comment: I dont know the file name.

Comment: find will recursive searches the pattern and pipes to grep. finally cut will display the file names.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU grep (likely, as you're on Linux), you might want to use this option:

> ## `--label=`*LABEL*
>
> Display input actually coming from standard input as input coming from file `LABEL`.  This is especially useful when implementing tools like `zgrep`, e.g., `gzip -cd foo.gz | grep --label=foo -H  something`.   See
>                 also the `-H` option.

So you'd have something like

```
for f in *.docx
do unzip -p "$f" word/document.xml \
    | sed -e "$sed_command" \
    | grep -H --label="$f" "$1"
done
```